# Single output from multiple selects

Tags: javascript

This has been driving me nuts for over a week now and I have yet to even find someone else trying to do the same thing.

Essentially I am trying to get a single output from multiple HTML select options, with only the latest showing up.

Example HTML & JS that is not working:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySelect");
  var i = x.selectedIndex;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.options[i].text;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select class="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
  </select>
  <select class="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
  </select>
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Now, if I do the same with a single select and use an ID instead of a Class it works just fine.

Example working single select:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var i = x.selectedIndex;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.options[i].text;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
  </select>
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

I am completely stumped, and the "undefined" error tells me absolutely nothing.
I just can't figure out what is wrong.

All I want is to have multiple selects and only output the last selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySelect");` is an array an wouldn't work with your approach.
Do something like this.

```js
function myFunction(select) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = select.value;
  //or text 
  //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select class="mySelect" onchange="myFunction(this)">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
  </select>
  <select class="mySelect" onchange="myFunction(this)">
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
  </select>
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

I could have sworn I tried to get the value but ran into errors.
Short and easy, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The `getElementsByClassName()` method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList object.

The NodeList object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0

.You need an index after `getElementsByClassName`like this `getElementsByClassName("className:)[0]` .

An easy way of remembering it if there is elements then array will be returned, if it's element single object will be returned.

For what you need it can be done by passing reference of the object using `this` keyword in the function

```js
function myFunction(obj) {
  var x = obj;
  var i = x.selectedIndex;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.options[i].text;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select class="mySelect" onchange="myFunction(this)">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
  </select>
  <select class="mySelect" onchange="myFunction(this)">
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
  </select>
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much as well.
I found this method to be easier when using an assigned value to the options.